# Need help getting height of image (Possible Inheritance Problem)

Tags: java, image, inheritance, casting, project

Ok so this is the KernelHandler Class

`public class KernelHandler extends ImageHandler`

I'm getting a cannot find method getWidth()

I know it has something to do with inheritance, but I need help, please

`//Heres the contructor`

```
 public KernelHandler(String nameOfFile)
{
   super(nameOfFile);


    }

// here's the super constructor
public ImageHandler(String  nameOfFile){


     URL imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(nameOfFile);
    try
    {
     myImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "image missing" );
    }
```

`// Here's the method were trying to use`

`public static int numOfRedBoxes(String nameOfImg)`

```
    {
        KernelHandler myHand = new KernelHandler(nameOfImg);
        for(int i = 0; i < myHand.getWidth(); i++)

            for(int j = 0; j < myHand.getHeight(); j++){
                if(img.getRGB(i, j) == red){
                    numOfRedBoxes++;
               }   
            }
       }
      return numOfRedBoxes;
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651499/need-help-getting-height-of-image-possible-inheritance-problem looks very similar

Comment: it is (it's mine) I just forgot to log in so i can't comment or edit it

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: You can [request that the two accounts be merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801).

Comment: I already merged them.  *With my mind.*

Answer (score 0):

`getWidth()` should not have private access in `ImageHandler` (or package private access if both classes are in different packages). Could you check that?

Simply put, `getWidth()` should be prefixed with `public` or `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of myHand to that of the super class , it would be something like:

```
ImageHandler myHand = new KernelHandler(nameOfImg);
```

Comment: ImageHandler myHand = new KernelHandler(nameOfImg);

Answer (score 0):

Is there a method named getWidth() in ImageHandler? I have seen some implementations of this class that do not.  That could be another reason why it is not accessible.

Comment: There is not one in imageHandler. Could I make one in ImageHandler that basically mimics the BufferedImage getWidth()?

Comment: I can not think of any reason why you shouldn't be able to.  I am not sure which version you are using but this one: http://www.hcilab.org/documents/tutorials/Brother/src/javadoc/core/doc/org/hcilab/btprinter/abstractionlayer/ImageHandler.html has static variables for the max image height and max image width that is supported by the printer.  I am not sure if that will help you too much though.  What are you planning on using the width and height for?